# GUI library for PyPy

Tags: user-interface, pypy

Is there presently any GUI library that can be used for development in PyPy?

Comment: PyPy is just a Python implementation. Is there a reason that you're asking specifically about PyPy?

Comment: I am starting to use it just for the fun of exploring it and am wondering if there is a gui library I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no GUI working with PyPy as of now, except wxPython ([blog post](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2010/05/running-wxpython-on-top-of-pypy.html)). I use web-based UIs for stuff that I do anyway, but that's probably irrelevant.

Comment: Since then, Tkinter became an option: http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-tkinter-and-idle-with-pypy.html

Answer (score 3):

Gtk+ can be used using the python package "pgi".

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgi

pgi is a pure-python library for talking to GObject libraries such as Gtk. It's therefore compatible with both C-Python and PyPy, and since it can use cffi it should be extremely efficient with PyPy.

I have tested this on Linux, it's likely to also work on OS X, I'm less sure about Windows.

If you substutite `from gi.repository` with `from pgi.repository` in the following tutorial, it should get you started: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: How about GTK2?

Answer (score 2):

*Qt for Python* (PySide6) is about to become a Gui tool for PyPy. At least there is much activity on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-535 at the moment, and they are planning to get *Qt for PyPy* ready still in this year.